# Not able to receive Push notification with distribution certificates

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am currently implementing the push notification for my app. I have successfully implemented PNS with the developer provisional profile and able to receive the notifications. But when I implement it by distribution provisional profile and add the ipa file in device then it ask for the permission but when the notification is send, it's not receive on the device.

Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

may be you forget to remove "sandbox" from the "push link"

Comment: i make 'sandbox=false' from my .net server

Comment: ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -> ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195

Comment: do i need .pem file ? because i haven't use it so far. i am using the p12 file only. is it necessary to make .pem file for distribution cetificate for push notifications?

Comment: yes the permission was asked when i install ipa file to the device

Comment: i mean a response from server when you try to push.

Answer (score 1):

1) for sending pns on developer certificate you have to ON the sandbox and when you want to send pns on distribution certificate than you have to OFF the sandbox.

2) check your code signing when you creating your ipa file is that signed with correct distribution certificate.

3) check your distribution certificate is with ad-hoc or not.

4) check your device is that registered with your certificate or not.!!

i hope this will help you.!!